# Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'interface'. eslint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to use Props in my code and I'm getting the following error on (interface - "Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'interface'. (3:0)eslint").

I'm using next with TypeScript to develop this project.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgqOA.png)

```js
import { TitleStyled, SubTitle } from "./Title.style";

interface TitleProps {
    titulo: String;
    subtitulo?: String | JSX.Element;
}

export default function Title(props: TitleProps) {
    return (
        <>
            <TitleStyled>{props.titulo}</TitleStyled>

            <SubTitle>{props.subtitulo}</SubTitle>
        </>
    );
}
```

My package.json

```js
{
  "name": "pets",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.4",
    "@next/font": "13.1.1",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/react": "18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
    "eslint": "8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.1",
    "next": "13.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.4"
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried renaming your file `Title.tsx` instead of `Title.jsx`?

Comment: I simply renamed the file to .tsx and it solved my problem, thanks a lot for your help.